# Zabbix Auto Discovery by ping

Tags: discovery, zabbix, autodiscovery

I would like to add all newly discovered hosts to a host group AutoDiscovered.

I have added:

```
Action: Auto Discovery Ping
Conditions: Discovery rule = Ping
Operation: Add to host groups: AutoDiscovered
```

Discovery Rule:

```
Name: Ping
Range: 192.168.0.0/23
Delay: 60
Checks: ICMP ping
Unique: IP address
Enabled: Y
```

I wait 60 seconds, but the Zabbix host does not start pinging hosts. I get no output from:

```
tcpdump -n not port 22 and host zabbix.server and not port 80 and not port 53
```

I had Zabbix to start pinging like crazy. Why does this not happen?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to be patient: 1 hour later hosts started trickling in.